# Using a TypeScript onChange handler to update state for an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onchange

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm trying to gain experience by building small applications. I'm working on a form that will compile a list of game names and URL strings, with the ability for the user to add and remove additional entries. The logic for adding or removing an object from the array is working, but I'm having difficulty with the onChange handlers to handle dynamic values.

```
// interface for each game object
interface GameObj {
    title: string;
    steamUrl: string;
}

export const AddGameForm: React.FC<AddGameFormProps> = ({ ...props }) => {
    // initial state
    const [list, setList] = useState<GameObj[]>([{ title: '', steamUrl: '' }]);

.....

const handleTitleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const {
      name,
      value,
      dataset: { id }
    } = e.target;
    console.log(name, value, id);

    // use id prop to find the correct array object and update the title property
  };

  const handleURLChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const {
      name,
      value,
      dataset: { id }
    } = e.target;
    console.log(name, value, id);

    // use id prop to find the correct array object and update the steamUrl property
  };
```

I have separate onChange handlers for the title and steamUrl properties and I've been able to access the data-id attributes, however I have not been able to use the id to update the correct object's property. I've tried to make a copy of the state, alter it and save it using the state setter, as well as attempt to use a callback function in the setter but I keep receiving TS errors such as 'Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.' for the id. I have a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-heyrovsky-e86z0h?file=/src/index.tsx:689-1240) for this issue but I'm drawing a blank on how to proceed.

Comment: First of all, your inputs have a value set, so its value can never change. It is a controlled component, https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html and you would need to implement updating the value yourself on every keystroke. Second, updatedList[id].title = value is an object mutation. React will never pick this up and know to re-render. You must call a state setter.

Comment: I thought that linking the input to the specific object in the array inside the `.map()` call would tie the input value to the state? It looks similar to how the multiple inputs example in the reactjs docs to me. Should I not link the value to the state?

Also I am trying to call the state setter however I'm not sure how to locate the specific array element and alter the property that matched the `name` attribute.

Comment: you need to think about React in terms of renders. What does the data looks like at the time of renders? When are you rendering? React has no way to know to render itself when you mutate an object. It doesn't periodically render to see if the underlying data has changed, you must tell it to render, by setting state. No calls to setState, no renders. (essentially) If your change handler doesn't call a state setter, there will be no render. Store your data in state somewhere, call the state setter as needed, and react will handle the rest.

Comment: I want to point out another mistake OP made from sandbox: this line `const updatedList = list`, since javascript object/array is `passed by reference`, updatedList is the exact same as list itself, so if you wish to make a copy of the original list, use spread operator instead `const updatedList = [...list]`.